# GET html data from multiple urls on website in one connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib3

I have a python script that takes in an input of a few urls. My script loops through each of these urls and prints out the htmltext from each page. Would the website see this as 3 seperate GET requests and therefore 3 "hits" to the site or would it see the socket connection and see it as 1 "hit" to the page?

I think it's the first option by checking the debug, if so, is it possible to GET data from multiple URLs on the same site but the site to only see this as 1 "hit" to the site? Can I utilise the keep-alive functionality to achieve this in urllib3?

My script is below:

```
for u in url:
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    req = urllib2.Request(u)
    req.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0')
    print urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)).open(req)
    resp = opener.open(req)
    htmltext = resp.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Would the website see this as 3 seperate GET requests and therefore 3 "hits" to the site or would it see the socket connection and see it as 1 "hit" to the page?

Yes, even if you reuse socket connections, it is still 3 distinct requests (over one socket). The server's access log will show 3 requests regardless of how many connections you've used.

The benefit of reusing connections is that creating a new TCP socket and negotiating the handshake with the server is a relatively expensive procedure. It can sometimes take more time to do that than retrieve the HTTP response body itself. By reusing a connection, you can skip that part after the first request.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to GET the data from 3 different URLs but the server not being aware?

Comment: The server has to be aware of the URLs it is serving, otherwise how would it serve them?

Comment: I was hoping of a way around it. Is it therefore possible to open a connection to a website and have a continous GET? An example website once you browse to the page some of the data in the page updates automatically without refreshing the page is it possible to simulate this in python?

Comment: It's not a limitation of the client but rather the design of the HTTP protocol. As long as you're speaking HTTP, each request is interpreted separately by the server and will be logged accordingly. If that is a problem, then you need to use a different protocol with a different kind of server. :)